# Check Validate Text in Textbox + Windows Forms

Tags: vb.net, text, textbox, validation

I am new to Win Forms, I have a scenario here..

When User enter ID in a textbox, I want to check that value in database and get the name for that ID before submitting the Submit Button.

In webforms it can be done using OnFoucs and OnBlur events but how can I do here before submitting the button.

I am using .NET 1.1

Regards
SBMARYA

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am able to do it using Leave Event of the TextBox control.

```
Private Sub txtID_Leave(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles txtID.Leave

End Sub
```

Thanks
sbmarya